# Django REST Serializer make all fields allow_null or not required

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I need to apply `extra_kwargs` on all fields in a model (Over 20 fields), except one or two.

I know one method is:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     field1 = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True,required=False)
```

or

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
          model = MyModel
          fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'field1': {'required': False, 'allow_null': True},}
```

But it gets too inefficient when I have to apply this to each field one by one.

Is there anything that can help me do something like this ?

```
        extra_kwargs = {
            '__all__': {'required': True, 'allow_null': False},
```

Comment: *"..... it gets too inefficient ...."*, No, it is not ***inefficient***, It is the DRF way.

Comment: Do you think the below answer is helpful for your issue? you can [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) and [give it an upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments). It will allow other people in the community facing the same issue to find their answers much more effortlessly.

Answer (score 0):

One approach on this topic can be like below code snippet as `MySerializer` class:

```py
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {field.name:{'required': False, 'allow_null': True} for field in MyModel._meta.get_fields()}
```